# How can i use android.intent categories more than one?

Tags: android, android-intent, categories

Like this: (This is broke)

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.IKI"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.MAINIKI" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.UC"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.MAINUC" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.**DEFAULT**" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Problem is the bold code. How can i use that activity? What is other categories that are choosable? Is there? What should i do?

Comment: bold code: * * DEFAULT * *

Comment: I suggest that you look at [the docs for the <comment> tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html). In particular, that page gives links to a more detailed discussion about Intents and Intent Filters and to the Intent class javadocs.

Comment: I found a solution, i can use intent filters. But have i use class? For example;

<activity class=".NoteEditor" android:label="@string/title_note">
             <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
             </intent-filter>

Comment: <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
             </intent-filter>

         </activity>

Comment: And what is android:label? How can i use them?

Comment: Are you asking a new question? If so you should click the "Post a Question button". If you are simply adding information to your current question, please click the edit link directly below it.

Comment: The `android:label` attribute is what will be displayed in the title bar when your activity is active.

Answer (score 2):

you may use different activity when you have more than one main activity class in your project.

Comment: What is activity class? Where are they? how can i edit this commands?

<activity
            android:name="com.example.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.IKI"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.MAINIKI" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.UC"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.MAINUC" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I wanna startup my program, then i click button, then i'll see second layout. Then i'll click button (in second layout), i'll see third layout. I did first (clicked button in first page, saw second layout), But i couldn't do second. Of course program will not just this.. I'll make 20-21 layouts in total.

Comment: in your code <activity android:name=""> here the android:name is define your activity class..

Comment: activity class means your main class which is perform some activity and extended by activity.